# Microsoft SpeechSynthesizer crackles when outputting to files and streams

Tags: c#, powershell, audio, text-to-speech

I'm writing a thing that uses the SpeechSynthesizer to generate wave files on request, but I'm having problems with crackling noises. The weird thing is that output directly to the sound card is just fine.

This short powershell script demonstrates the issue, though I'm writing my program in C#.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Speech
$speech = New-Object System.Speech.Synthesis.SpeechSynthesizer
$speech.Speak('Guybrush Threepwood, mighty pirate!')
$speech.SetOutputToWaveFile("${PSScriptRoot}\foo.wav")
$speech.Speak('Guybrush Threepwood, mighty pirate!')
```

What this *should* do, is output to the speakers, and then save that same sound as "foo.wav" next to the script.

What it does is output to the speakers, and then save a crackling, old record player sounding version as a wave file. I've tested this on three different machines, and though they select different voices by default (all Microsoft provided default ones), they all sound like garbage falling down stairs in the wave file.

Why?

EDIT: I am testing this on Windows 10 Pro, with the latest updates that add that annoying "People" button on the taskbar.

EDIT 2: [Here's a link to an example sound generated with the above script. Notice the crackling voice, that's not there when the script outputs directly to the speakers.](https://instaud.io/1zp5)

EDIT 3: [It's even more noticeable with a female voice](https://instaud.io/1zsO)

EDIT 4: [The same voice as above, saved to file with TextAloud 3 - no cracking, no vertical spikes.](https://instaud.io/1zt1)

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Sounds the same to me, no matter if I save the result in a file or play the speech right off.

Comment: Could I bother you to upload your wav file somewhere? That site I used is very simple and requires no registration. If it's simply my sound cards or wav file playback setup, your wav file should come out being identical to mine.

Or, do you hear crackle playing my wav?

Comment: I think I shared my foo.wav file at https://instaud.io/1zsv

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to have the same crackles as mine, however. One can even see them on the graphs instaud.io makes, as two vertical lines in the middle of the word "pirate", and several other places albeit not as pronounced.

I am convinced that I'm not hearing these when the scripts outputs directly to the speakers. I even tried on a fourth machine now, a small laptop I got recently - same result.

Comment: I added another sound file to my question, this time with a female voice. Again the crackles are also visible as vertical lines, so it shouldn't be the playback equipment.

Comment: ..and I added a fourth file, testing with TextAloud 3 now - no crackle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the SpeechSynthesizer API, which simply provides bad quality, crackling audio as seen in the samples above. The solution is to do what TextAloud does, which is to use the SpeechLib COM objects directly.

This is done by adding a COM reference to "Microsoft Speech Object Library (5.4)". Here is a snippet of the code I ended up with, which produces audio clips of the same quality as TextAloud:

```
public new static byte[] GetSound(Order o)
{
    const SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags speechFlags = SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync;
    var synth = new SpVoice();
    var wave = new SpMemoryStream();
    var voices = synth.GetVoices();
    try
    {
        // synth setup
        synth.Volume = Math.Max(1, Math.Min(100, o.Volume ?? 100));
        synth.Rate = Math.Max(-10, Math.Min(10, o.Rate ?? 0));
        foreach (SpObjectToken voice in voices)
        {
            if (voice.GetAttribute("Name") == o.Voice.Name)
            {
                synth.Voice = voice;
            }
        }
        wave.Format.Type = SpeechAudioFormatType.SAFT22kHz16BitMono;
        synth.AudioOutputStream = wave;
        synth.Speak(o.Text, speechFlags);
        synth.WaitUntilDone(Timeout.Infinite);

        var waveFormat = new WaveFormat(22050, 16, 1);
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])wave.GetData()))
        using (var reader = new RawSourceWaveStream(ms, waveFormat))
        using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new WaveFileWriter(outStream, waveFormat))
        {
            reader.CopyTo(writer);
            return o.Mp3 ? ConvertToMp3(outStream) : outStream.GetBuffer();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(voices);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wave);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(synth);
    }
}
```

This is the code to convert a wave file to mp3. It uses NAudio.Lame from nuget.

```
internal static byte[] ConvertToMp3(Stream wave)
{
    wave.Position = 0;
    using (var mp3 = new MemoryStream())
    using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(wave))
    using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(mp3, reader.WaveFormat, 128))
    {
        reader.CopyTo(writer);
        mp3.Position = 0;
        return mp3.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you add a reference to `Microsoft Speech Object Library`? What I need to specify in `/reference` for csc?

Comment: In my Visual Studio .Net (not core, which can't do this AFAIK) project, I right clicked References => Add Reference => COM => Microsoft Speech Object Library version 5.4

Answer (score 1):

I find it hard to believe this is a PoSH issue.
It's not PoSH doing the encoding on the serialization to disk. Its the API/Class that is being used.

'msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx'

As per the MSDN, there is no option to control the encoding, bit rate, etc.

.wav has never been HQ stuff. So, I'd wonder if you take that .wav through a converter to make it an .mp3 or mp4, if that would correct your quality concerns.  But that also means getting the converter on users systems.

Secondly, since Win8, the default player does not even play .wav correctly or at all. Sure, you can still set the default play of .wav to Windows Media Player or call the file via VLC, but it's still a .wav file. Yet, that also means, you having to set the Media Player assignment on every target system.

Comment: It is indeed an API issue, as it happens in C# as well. You are wrong, however, about the quality of wave files, and the API does have options for setting the quality when you use the [SetOutputToAudioStream method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer.setoutputtoaudiostream(v=vs.110).aspx).

About the quality, wave is what was generally used on slow computers that could not encode CD audio to mp3 directly due to limits on processing power. It does not reduce the quality (though mp3 does).

Comment: I messed with that SetOutputToAudioStream, and it did not make a difference in any attempt I tried. Hence my previous response. But you seem to have spent way more time with than I, so, I'll have to take your word on it. I've not had issue with .mp3/mp4 formats when used live or serialized however.

Comment: It can't do much, as each voice is generally limited in itself. For instance, the voices from [Ivona](https://www.ivona.com/) are generally 22kHz, or more accurately 22050 Hz, meaning that if you sample them at 44.1kHz, all you're doing is getting two of each sample in a file twice as large. You can run less samples, though, if you hate your ears.